# Laravel 5.3 Chinese characters issue with JSON

Tags: postgresql, laravel

I'm having a problem with Eloquent. I have a Postgres DB set in `UTF-8`. Using DataGrip (or any other DB app) I got the result right.

Eloquent is trying to parse the Chinese characters, so when I do a `toJson()` or `json_encode` I got a failure.

I double checked my DB, is working fine, the problem looks like to be with `Laravel::DB` or `Eloquent` it-self.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, another script was converting the value using ucwords(mb_strtolower($item->name, 'UTF-8')).

Sorry about that.